# I want to distinguish between true digit and a string digit

Tags: python, digits, python-3.10

I want to check a 'x' string whether it is a digit or not in advance.

'1' is naturally a digit.

But and I will use ① what is calld a string number very much.

I don't know the range of string numbers IDE judges as a digit.

`'①'.isdigit()` returns True.

`'⑴'.isdigit()` returns True.

`'ⅰ'` or `'Ⅰ'` returns False.

`'㈠'` returns False. (kanji version of (1) )

`'❶'` returns True.

I want to do like this.

```
for s in data:
    if s.isdigit():
       int_ = int(s)
```

If I accept `'①'`, `int` will throw an error. Now, I write try:except for it.

Because I'm a japanese, I often use `'①'` or `'⑴'`

How to distinguish isdigit or not isdigit in advance?

Should I rely on try:except or counting all of them in advance?

regular expression?

The main problem is I don't know what is judged as a digit.

```
data = ["1", "23", "345", "①", "(1)", "(2)"]
```

This data is dynamic value. It will be changed every time.

Moreover, the string like this may expand in the future.

I hope the string of `isdigit() == True` is accepted by `int()`.

I don't have an urgent problem because of try: except.

Comment: If the property you're looking to test for is "will `int` accept this string as input", then the way to go about that is to call `int` on it. Methods like `isdigit` test for obscure Unicode character properties that do not correspond to what you're looking for.

Comment: "I don't know the range of string numbers IDE judges as a digit": you don't have to know. It's not the IDE's decision. It is built into the character set of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the [`str.isdecimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal) method fits your requirements. It excludes strings like `'①'`, but includes other strings like `'١'` which are accepted by `int`.

```py
>>> int('١')                
1
```

Comment: But it does *not* accept `'-1'`, which `int` accepts. The whole "test for digits" thing is probably the wrong idea in the first place.

Comment: The question includes string with multiple characters, so negative integers could potentially be possible input. Otherwise, I think that using a method is probably more clear and less clunky than the try except `ValueError` though, so long as there's not other edge cases to worry about.